# Label Ticks on x axis are coming in alternatively

Tags: javascript, c#, charts, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using `Chart Helper` for showing a bar chart. but in my chart labels on x-axis are coming in alternate fashion.
This is what is wrote for generating the chart

```
var myChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 900,theme:ChartTheme.Blue).AddTitle("Policy6 Coverage Visualization").AddSeries(chartType:"column", xValue: GraphData, xField: "Name", yValues: GraphData, yFields: "policy6").Write();
```

[image: This is the screenshot]

Comment: Look like they are __too long/too dense__ to come in a single line..

Comment: Yes they are. can i force to show it?

Comment: Hm, maybe I got the image wrong - xxx is a label but what about PACT_IN_... ? Is that also a Label?

Comment: yes.  PACT_IN_ that is also a label.

Comment: OK, then I believe you can't 'force' the chart to show potentially overlapping labels. Try to limit their size or choose a smaller or denser font!

Comment: i tried rotating the axis also. but labels are showing same behaviors in Y-Axis also.